# PHPMailer no guarda las variables

Tags: ajax, formularios, email, phpmailer

la otra vez vine aquí preguntando como podía hacer para que me lleguen los mails de phpmailer y pude resolver la cuestion. Hoy vengo para pedirles ayuda porque me llega el mail pero no la informacion del mismo, digo, solicito un nombre y apellido, un correo electronico y un mensaje pero no me llegan.

En el body puse codigo html para que quedara mejor a la vista y sí me lee el codigo html pero no las variables. para solucionarlo intenté con un `require` pero no funcionó.
Cabe aclarar que el formulario es vía ajax.

Formulario HTML

```
                    <input type="text" required id="nombre" class="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name:" minlength="3" maxlength="15">
                    <input type="text" required id="apellido" class="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Lastname:" minlength="2" maxlength="50">
                    <input type="email" required name="mail" id="mail" class="mail" placeholder="Mail:">
                    <textarea name="texto" required id="texto" class="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Tell us your project..." minlength="50"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-send" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
```

Archivo PHPMailer

```
<?php
require 'views/index-view.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $apellido = htmlspecialchars($_POST['apellido'],ENT_QUOTES);
    $correo = $_POST['mail'];
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
}
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'gator4021.hostgator.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '***';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '***';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('***');
    $mail->addAddress('***');     // Add a recipient             

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "Correo enviado desde Programmark.com";
    $mail->Body    = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <h3>Nombre: $nombre</h3>
        <br>
        <h3>Apellido: $apellido</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Correo: $correo</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Mensaje: </h3>
        <p>$texto</p>
    </body>
    </html>";
    $mail->send();
```

Archivo Ajax

```
$('#formulario').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let formulario = $(this).serialize();
        let nombre = $('#nombre').val(),
            apellido = $('#apellido').val(),
            correo = $('#mail').val(),
            text = $('#texto').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "../enviarCorreo.php",
                data: {name: nombre, lastname: apellido, email: correo, texto: text},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#formulario').trigger('reset');
                    alert('The form has been sent successfully!');
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert('The form could not be sent')
                },  
            })  
    });
```

Captura de como me llega el mail:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeecría mucho que me ayuden para solucionar el tema de las variables

Answer (score 0):

En tu Archivo PHPMailer estás mandando desde el Ajax tus variables con otro nombre, las mandas en inglés especificamente:

```
data: {name: nombre, lastname: apellido, email: correo, texto: text},
```

Y en el Archivo PHPMailer podrías probar esto:

```
// Esto solo es para asegurar que las variables sean globales.
$nombre = "";
$apellido = "";
$correo = "";
$texto = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'],ENT_QUOTES);
$apellido = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname'],ENT_QUOTES);
$correo = $_POST['email'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];
}
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por contestar, puse lo que me dijiste y me sigue dando igual. El require que está al principio se lo dejo o se lo saco?